# How to make a simple click game in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write my first JavaScript game, it will be a block you click and every time you click it you get one point until you run out of time. Here is what I have so far... but the points don't go up when the onclick occurs..

```js
var click=0; 

function hi(){
    click+=1; 
}
document.write(click);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
        <button onclick="hi()" id="demo"> </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that.. You can't just change the variable value after the page was rendered and hope for it to change dynamically in the page.

Comment: You have to show `click` on the page, or in other words update the counter display.

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, typically a right answer is attempted given for any question, and there is no right answer to your question -- one can create a simple click game in a myriad different ways, and no one answer may cover them all or a "best" one, because no such way exists. I would recommend you read up on [JavaScript at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript), in particular look at the Tutorials section and also read up on event handling in JavaScript _after_ you've mastered the basics of the language itself. Also, don't forget HTML and CSS ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might help lead you on the path to your ultimate goal. Here is an example that increments the variable on button click and displays it both on the page and in an alert. There is also a reset button. You should be able to use this example to add any other functionality you need using the same principles of variable manipulation.

```js
var click=0; 
var c = document.getElementById("click");
function hi(){
    click+=1;
    alert("click = " + click);
    c.innerHTML = click;
}
function reset(){
    click=0;
    alert("click = " + click);
    c.innerHTML = click;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hi()" id="demo">add</button>
<button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<p id="click">0</p>
```

Comment: Super Helpful Thank you! I'll study this code...But is there anyway to make the points count on the page instead of an alert?

Comment: Well yeah, just remove the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
     <script>
      var click=0; 
var outOfTime = false;
function hi(){
if(!outOfTime){
click+=1; 
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = click;
}
}
var time = 60; //time in seconds
var timer = setInterval(function(){
 time--;
 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + "s";
 if(time==0){
   clearInterval(timer);
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time's up!";
   outOfTime = true;
 }
}, 1000);
      </script>
 </head>
 <body> Time remaining:
      <span id = "timer"> 60s</span><br/>
     Score:
       <span id="score">0</span><br/>
        <button onclick="hi()" id="demo"> </button>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi @hev1 I studied this code and I understand everything in it except for when you are setting intervals and in the brackets you refer to a "function". What is this doing?

Comment: @Kyle It sets an interval (in milliseconds) to repeat a function. Here, it is making the displayed time go down by 1 second every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Ahh so your setting an interval for that certain function, which is decrementing the time every one second until it hits zero! Thanks I get it.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, that's what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying click whenever you are changing its value.

```
var click=0; 
function hi(){
   click+=1;         
   alert(click) // document.write(click); 
}
```

This will work fine